# Firebase verify tokenToken through Firebase-Admin Error

Tags: node.js, firebase-authentication, firebase-admin

Hey I am trying to Verify User Token From Firebase Admin and then create a user based on that Information in Mongodb but Everytime when I request to this end point i got following error:

```
 D:\React Course\Ecommerce\server\node_modules\firebase-admin\lib\auth\base-auth.js:421
        if (properties?.providerToLink) {
                       ^

SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1180:10)
```

Here is my code For Verification of userToken

```
const express=require("express");
import admin  from "firebase-admin";

var serviceAccount = require("../FirebaseAdmin/Servicekey.json");

admin.initializeApp({
    credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
  });

export const authcheck=async(req,res,next)=>{
try{ 
    const firebaseuser=await admin.auth().verifyIdToken(req.headers.authcheck);
    console.log(firebaseuser);
}catch(error){
    console.log(error);
}
}
```

Can anyone Please Help me out on This I tried every possible way
Here is the Console.log of req.headers
[image]

And This is from Client side Where i am requesting to my end point

```
const createandupdateuser=async(authcheck)=>{
  await axios.post("http://localhost:5000/api/create-and-update-user",{},{
    headers:{
      authcheck,
    }
  })
  }
const handlesubmit=async(e)=>{
e.preventDefault();
try{
    setloading(true);
    const result=await signInWithEmailAndPassword(auth,email,password);
    const {user}=result;
    const Idtoken=await user.getIdTokenResult();
    createandupdateuser(Idtoken.token);
    dispatch({
      type:"LOGGED_IN_USER",
      payload:{
        email:user.email,
        token:Idtoken.token
      }
    })
    navigate("/");
}catch(error){
console.log(error)
swal(error.message);
setloading(false);
}
}
```

Here is The authcheck function called

```
const express=require("express");
const router=express.Router();
import {createandupdateuser} from "../controllers/auth"
const {authcheck} =require("../middlewares/index");

router.post("/create-and-update-user",authcheck,createandupdateuser);

module.exports=router;
```

Comment: Can you `console.log(req.headers)` and share a screenshot of output? Also, how are you passing the token at first place and how is express involved here? Please share complete code as is including the cloud function.

Comment: @Dharmaraj Question is Edited Please take a look

Comment: Are you logging the headers in `authcheck` function? Can you please share complete code and show where you are calling that function from?

Comment: I am passing token as argument in createandupdateuser function see the handleSubmit function
also i provie you console.log(req.headers) screenshot

Comment: Yes, but I am asking where is `export const authcheck =...` this function called from ?

Comment: Edit again with Required code Check again

Answer (score 1):

Update......I solved my Problem by Downgrading the Firebase-admin Version

```
npm i firebase-admin@10.3.0
```

Answer (score 0):

There is likely a hidden character among your code. Copy your code and paste it into a plain text editor and remove any junk text.

If you are using Visual Code you can turn on "Render whitespace".

Press `CTRL + SHIFT + P / CMD + SHIFT + P` and serach for "Render whitespace" and toggle it on

Comment: I tried Error still remain Same Any other Possible solution Please?

Comment: Could you provide the code for making a request to any endpoint where authcheck is running?

Im interested in your header

Comment: Question is Edited Please take a Look

Answer (score 0):

Hi I had a similar issue when deployed to vercel functions

Cannot find module './token-generator'
Require stack:

- /var/task/node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/auth/base-auth.js
- /var/task/node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/auth/tenant-manager.js
- /var/task/node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/auth/auth.js
- /var/task/node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/app/firebase-namespace.js
- /var/task/node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/default-namespace.js
- /var/task/node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/index.js
- /var/task/index.js
- /var/task/___now_launcher.js
- /var/runtime/index.mjs

I solved this issue by dowgrading to
npm i firebase-admin@10.3.0

Answer (score 0):

I'm having the same problem to day with both firebase-admin v11.x and v12.x

Reverting to v10.3.0 and my code works, no other changes required.

`firebase-admin@12.0.0  -- failed with same error as OP`

`firebase-admin@11.11.1 -- failed with same error as OP`

`firebase-admin@10.3.0 -- code runs as expected (no error, able to use Admin SDK API calls)`

***UPDATE***

This seems to be an ESM vs CJS issue.  My code runs as ESM (it is an older codebase using `node -r esm ...`) and the stack trace here and in the OP indicates `node:internal/modules/cjs/loader`.

Trying to build a repro is proving challenging....the issue goes away with a clean codebase and nice/proper handling of ESM.  The code works fine with v10, v11 and v12 in this configuration.